# Some mandatory paremeter candidates out of X parameters?

Tags: java, parameters, overloading

I'm having a design issue I cannot find a "proper" solution or pattern for. Let me explain by code.

```
//Mandatory set 1
int minDamage;
int maxDamage;

//Mandatory set 2
int damage;
```

Either mandatory set 1 or mandatory set 2 needs to be supplied to create this object. This can easily be tackled by two different overload constructors. But what if I add this mandatory sets?

```
//Mandatory set 3
int percentageBasedDamage;
```

I cannot have a overload both containing the the same single datatype. Yes I could make that last one a float but what happens if I add a couple of other mandatory sets? I eventually run out of data types. The builder pattern does not seem to help out here. The only thing I can think off is supplying all the mandatory methods but this could end up in a constructor with a lot of parameters. Also it is not clear how to use the object, I want it to either do min/max damage, a specified damage or a percentage based damage.

```
public class MyObject
{
  int minDamage;
  int maxDamage;
  int damage;
  int percentageBasedDamage;

  public MyObject(int minDamage, int maxDamage, int damage, int percentageBasedDamage)
  {
    this.minDamage = minDamage;
    //...
  }
}

MyObject myObject = new MyObject(10, 18, 0, 0); //Correct usage

MyObject myObject = new MyObject(0, 0, 5, 8); //Incorrect usage
```

Well there must be something Java has to offer to tackle this.

**Edit**

I actually thought a lot about using the builder pattern, but could not figure it out. Dark Knights answer eventually opened my eyes and I came up with this:

```
public class Damage extends Action {
String target;
String type;
int minDamage;
int maxDamage;
int damage;
int currentHealthPercentageDamage;
int maxHealthPercentageDamage;

private Damage(Builder build) {
    target = build.target;
    this.type = build.type;
    this.minDamage = build.minDamage;
    this.maxDamage = build.maxDamage;
    this.damage = build.damage;
    this.currentHealthPercentageDamage = build.currentHealthPercentageDamage;
    this.maxHealthPercentageDamage = build.maxHealthPercentageDamage;
}

public static class Builder
{

    private String target;
    private String type;
    private int minDamage;
    private int maxDamage;
    private int damage;
    private int currentHealthPercentageDamage;
    private int maxHealthPercentageDamage;

    public Builder(String target, String type) {
        this.target = target;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Damage minmax(int minDamage, int maxDamage)
    {
        this.minDamage = minDamage;
        this.maxDamage = maxDamage;
        return new Damage(this);
    }

    public Damage damage(int damage)
    {
        this.damage = damage;
        return new Damage(this);
    }

    public Damage currentHealthPercentageDamage(int currentHealthPercentageDamage)
    {
        this.currentHealthPercentageDamage = currentHealthPercentageDamage;
        return new Damage(this);
    }

    public Damage maxHealthPercentageDamage(int maxHealthPercentageDamage)
    {
        this.maxHealthPercentageDamage = maxHealthPercentageDamage;
        return new Damage(this);
    }

}
```

Since the build returns the Damage ones a single "mandatory set" has been chosen it is now properly designed and clear how this class should be instantiated and used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Builder pattern and let caller decide parameters to pass rather than forcing caller for different constructors. Refer [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2)

Comment: A builder would have the same issue. Only it's constructor takes the mandatory parameters.

Comment: @MennoGouw Here problem is we cannot add  constructor every time. Instead try to accommodate builder to handle it programatically.

Comment: I have thought about this. But the builder would have no mandatory parameters and a method to add each set. And thus it is still possible to end up with no parameters or too much parameters set. I could split them up in multiple classes but I imagine this would end up in a lot of classes that basically do the same.

Comment: Or wait... I could have the builder return the build after one of the sets is given and don't use a `build` method.

Comment: @MennoGouw Great going